# SQL Multiple Select Based on Key on a single table

Tags: sql

Thanks in advance if anyone here can answer.
I have this two tables:

```
      Strings                Numbers
 ----------------        ----------------
| ID  |  String  |      | ID  |  Number  |
 ----------------        ----------------
|  1  |    'A'   |      |  1  | 'First'  |
|  1  |    10    |      |  2  | 'Second' |
 ----------------       |  3  | 'Third'  |
|  2  |    'B'   |      |  4  | 'Fourth' |
|  2  |    11    |      |  5  | 'Fifth'  |
 ----------------        ----------------
|  3  |    'A'   |
|  3  |    12    |
 ----------------
|  4  |    'B'   |
|  4  |    13    |
 ----------------
|  5  |    'B'   |
|  5  |    14    |
 ----------------
```

For example, I filter the values "associated" with 'A', I have to get a table like this:

```
     Strings
 ----------------
| ID  |  String  |
 ---------------- 
|  1  |    10    |
 ---------------- 
|  3  |    12    |
 ----------------
```

And for instance, If wanna filter the values "associated" with 'B', I have to get a table like this:

```
      Strings
 ----------------
| ID  |  String  |
 ---------------- 
|  2  |    11    |
 ----------------
|  4  |    13    |
 ----------------
|  5  |    14    |
 ----------------
```

Again, thanks if you can help me.

Comment: what rdbms are you using? sql-server, mysql?

Answer (score 2):

Unless I am missing something you would use:

```
select s1.id, s1.string
from strings s1
inner join strings s2
    on s1.id = s2.id
    and s1.string != 'A'
    and s2.string = 'A'
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/92816/2)

Or

```
select s1.id, s1.string
from strings s1
inner join strings s2
    on s1.id = s2.id
    and s1.string != 'B'
    and s2.string = 'B'
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/92816/1)

Comment: +1 but is there any performance diff if I use `WHERE` in place of first `AND` - 
like here http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/92816/8

Comment: @sansix Have you reviewed the execution plans for both?  You will notice that they are the same -- http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/92816/12

Comment: ohh.. just checked that - so DB engine takes care of this?

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM Strings WHERE string = "A"
```

<sub>Substitute field names for the * as appropriate.</sub>

Answer (score 0):

```
select s2.ID,
       s2.String
  from Strings as s1
 inner join Strings as s2
    on s2.id = s1.id
   and s2.String != s1.String
 where s1.String = ?
```

However, this table structure is questionable. ID seems like it should be the primary key, but it can't be since there are multiple values. Also you never need the Numbers table so why include it in the question? :)